# How to use hashmap.put without overriding the previous data? (java)

Tags: java, hashmap, overriding

I have something along the lines of this:

```
public HashMap<Boolean, String> map = new HashMap();
map.put(this.inverted, "Inverted");
map.put(this.active, "Loading");
System.out.println(map.size());
```

after seeing that the size was always 1, I realised that using map.put was overriding the previous data. I am currently trying to iterate over the hashmap. Is there a way to add mappings to it without overriding previous ones?

Comment: make sure that the contend of the fields inverted and active are not the same and it will show 2

Comment: May be you need `Map<String, Boolean>` not `Map<Boolean, String>`

Answer (score 3):

You have declared your *HashMap* as: -

```
public HashMap<Boolean, String> map = new HashMap();
```

Now, just think how many maximum mapping can you have in your `map`? The answer you can get by thinking of, what all values can your `Boolean` type take. This is because, you cannot have duplicate keys in a `HashMap`.

So, probably you got it now, that you can at max have only `2 mappings` in your map, one for `true` and other for `false`(In fact you can have a `3rd` one too, as you can have a mapping for a `null` key too in your `HashMap`).

So, in your case, if both `this.inverted` and `this.active` are either `true` or `false`. Then only one of them can be there, and that would be the later value inserted.

> Is there a way to add mappings to it without overriding previous ones?

Probably you have build your *HashMap* wrongly. You should declare your map as: -

```
private Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap();
```

And now you can put two mappings as: -

```
map.put("Inverted", this.inverted);
map.put("Loading", this.active);
```

Comment: This is sure the correct answer, but the maximum size is 3 I think, including the "null" key, just a side note.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `this.inverted.equals(this.active)` and `this.inverted.hashcode()==this.active.hashcode()`

Maybe you need redefine the equals method for the key.

Comment: Do you realize that key is a Boolean which could be either `true` or `false`.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see the data type of the key.

Answer (score 0):

In MAP

An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value. ---> from [Map Api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

from your implementation, may be `this.inverted` and `this.active` both have same value.

Check the input once. print the keySet, then check.

or change the input to `Map<String, Boolean>`

Answer (score 0):

As @Frank suggest you should invert your Map.

```
public final Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("Inverted", this.inverted);
map.put("Loading", this.active);
System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the keys are the same than the previous value is overwritten in a standard Java Map. If you don't want this, you can have a look at a multimap which is implemented for example in  commons-collections. It can hold different values for one key.

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap is based on key/value pairs. If your keys are equal (they have the same hashcode), it will behave as you described.

For your use case, reversing your key/value pairs will help you.

```
public HashMap<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap();
map.put("Inverted", this.inverted); 
map.put("Loading", this.active);
System.out.println(map.size());
```

Answer (score -2):

[Get object of innermap ,by passing outer map key .. Then check if key of innermap exists then update values with previous data. else create new object of inner map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzZWB.png)

Comment: Above link contains image. Which solved data overriding issue.

Comment: Please add the code here as text instead of posting a link with an image